# How to store data from fetch get request

Tags: javascript, get, request, fetch, store

I want to store data from fetch GET request so i can do pagination.
I tried storing with localStorage but sometimes it works and this time it doesnt.

This is my code

```
const renderAllUsers = () => {

  let myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);

  let requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: "follow",
  };

  fetch("/users", requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((result) => {
      const res = JSON.parse(result);
      console.log(res);

      const userlist = localStorage.setItem("userlist", res);
      console.log(userlist);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
};
```

Console.log(res) = (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] - array of objects like i want it

Console.log(userlist) = undefined

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

`setItem` always returns `undefined`

Your data is in `res`. Just use that.